# Theorem regarding Open Sets

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I see the following theorem being used loosely to show measurability for all kinds of sets, **without stating whether they are open or not**, and was wondering if I was missing something.

The theorem states that every open set in $\mathbb{R}^d$ can be written as the countable union of almost disjoint boxes. (The term *almost disjoint* means the interior of the boxes is disjoint).

Answer (score 0):

product topology is defined in the way that every projection is continuous.

$R^d=R\times...\times R$, $d$ times

a projection $\pi_i(x_1,...,x_d):R^d\rightarrow R_i$ is continuous if for an open set $U\subset R_i$

the inverse image is open in $R_d$.

I.E. $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open in $R^d$

so all open sets in $R^d$ are products of open sets in $R$.

now an open set in $R$ can be written as the countable disjoint union of intervals.

so every open set if $R^d$ is the disjoint union of product of open sets in $R$.

Comment: Thank you, but how can I apply the theorem to any kind of set, if I don't know that it is **open**?